# Symmetric DS simple configuration guidance

Tags: postgresql, symmetricds

Over the past couple of weeks I have been prototyping out some examples in symmetric DS. Looking for some guidance and examples because I am really running into some walls here. I have used the server and android examples successfully, don't need any assistance with setup on getting the basics working. It is a complex tool and I;m still learning it as well.

So I am trying to setup an environment where all the clients that run on android device sync up to a server. So I know it's fairly straight forward to do a setup where its 1 MASTER -> <- multiple clients, as the example that they provide do.

What I am trying to do is multiple masters to multiple clients. Essentially I want a database on the server for each client. Ill attach a diagram to try to help explain but I want a database for each store so store #1 has a master DB on the server and it syncs both ways with the client device.

[server-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXos.png)

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS requires having a central node to store the configuration. I would recommend to have a central node with bunch of databases that connect to the central database. Connect each android application to another database. This topology will allow configuring what data syncs from the central node to the bunch of databases and what goes back

Comment: Why? What’s the relationship between the other and this question?

Comment: I found you as a one of the top users related to tag Struts and I don't know another way to  draw your attention, Борис. Because that it is really legacy technology it is highly unlikely that anyone will answer. I understand that it is not an appropriate approach but I wasted huge amount of time and I really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

On the router from client to server you can set the target catalog to be a variable : $(sourceExternalId).   This will use the clients external id as the database name on your server.

If you also need to replicate data back down you can set the external select on the triggers at the server.   This would need to be an expression on your server database that would evaluate the current database.  This would fire when a change occurs on the server database and populate the external_data column on sym_data during capture with the database that the change occurred in.   You would then adjust the router from server to client to be a column match router type.   Your expression then for the router would be: EXTERNAL_DATA=:EXTERNAL_ID.   This would ensure that this data only be sent to the appropriate client.